# on delete cascade sql not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created two tables `users` and `login_flag` below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    priv varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unlocked',
    ctime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_flag (
    flag_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    flag int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (flag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

mysql> select * from users;

| user_id | email          | first_name | last_name | password                                                     | priv  | status   | ctime               |

|       1 | admin@test.com | admin      | admin     | $2b$12$oMMYOM45LxzsibodyPPBx.JUocceiBoU0Ui2TrZaKEmXnhO0jkCTW | admin | unlocked | 2018-08-23 11:02:40 |

mysql> select * from login_flag;
+---------+---------+------+
| flag_id | user_id | flag |
+---------+---------+------+
|       1 |       1 |    0 |
+---------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I delete the record from  the `users` table:

```
mysql> delete from users where user_id='1';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)
```

This should also remove the entry from the table `login_flag` but it didn't happened that way.

```
mysql> select * from login_flag;
+---------+---------+------+
| flag_id | user_id | flag |
+---------+---------+------+
|       1 |       1 |    0 |
+---------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone just point me in the right direction or let me know where i am doing wrong.

I have also checked the `foreign_key_checks` and its value is `ON`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can see Engine is InnoDB

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS where Name = 'users'
    -> ;
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| users | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |  10485760 |              2 | 2018-08-23 11:58:47 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

`show create table login_flag;`

```
mysql> show create table login_flag;
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| login_flag | CREATE TABLE `login_flag` (
  `flag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flag` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`flag_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `login_flag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.  `REFERENCES user(user_id)` instead of `REFERENCES users(user_id)` ... you don't have a "user" table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen really my bad, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I made the changes still not working

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM? Foreign keys only work with InnoDB tables.

Comment: you mean InnoDB engine? , how can i get that information, is it MyISAM or something else

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS where Name = 'my table'` and check the value of the `Engine`

Comment: @hotfix engine is InnoDB updated the post.

Comment: Is the foreign key working at all? Try inserting a row into `login_flag` with a clearly bogus `user_id` value (e.g. -2147400000)

Comment: @Hackaholic run `show create table login_flag;` and see whether the foreign key constraint is shown in the DDL ?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Updated the post.

Comment: is `delete` and the next `select` in the same transaction?

Comment: @hotfix yes it is in same transaction

Comment: @Hackaholic it's weird. It should work well. I can only suggest to drop the FK and add it again and see if it works.

Comment: Does DELETE query remove record from `users` table?

Comment: @Devart Yes Delete query remove the record from the users table

Comment: Could you show full script (with some data) to reproduce?